# Delphi tcustomcontrol/twincontrol

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tcustomcontrol

Can someone please explain me which control is better to create custom componens? What is the difference between twincontrol and tcustomcontrol?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `TCustomControl` is windowed.  Maybe you are thinking of `TGraphicControl` instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can someone please explain me which control is better to create custom componens?

That depends on what kind of component you are making and what its requires are.

Is it visual?

- If no, use `TComponent`.
- if yes, does it need its own `HWND` (input focus, window messages, etc)?

  - If no, use `TGraphicControl`.
  - If yes, does it need to custom paint itself?

    - if yes, use `TCustomControl`.
    - if no, use `TWinControl`.

> What is the difference between twincontrol and tcustomcontrol?

`TCustomControl` is a `TWinControl` descendant that adds some additional handling for the `WM_PAINT` message, on top of what `TWinControl` does.  `TCustomControl` exposes a public `Canvas` property that you can draw on.  During painting, it enables the `csCustomPaint` flag in the `ControlState` property, and then calls a virtual `Paint()` method that your component can override.  So the benefit of `TCustomControl` is that it makes custom painting a little easier to manage.  Nothing more.

Comment: Thank you Remy Lebeau that is very good explanation for me, it gave me a really good understanding, can i ask what  does a hwnd do for a component? Is it used for to get focus?

Comment: An `HWND` is a Win32 data type that represents a window.  All UI controls at the OS level are windows and thus require an `HWND`. Yes, input focus is part of that system (but there is more to it than just that). Delphi takes things a step further by introducing *graphical* controls in addition to *windowed* controls. A graphical control lives inside of  windowed control. As such, it is still visible to the user, and can even be clicked on, but cannot receive input focus from the OS. Only windowed controls can have focus.